# Correct Syntax for Static Method Parameter in ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory

Tags: spring-integration

What is the correct syntax for a string expression meant to reference a call to a static function, when passed as a parameter to ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory?

As an example, I have a static function that returns a java.util.Date within a utility class:

```
public class DateTimeUtils {

  private DateTimeUtils() {throw new IllegalStateException("Utility class");}

  public static Date currentDeliveryDate() {

    ZonedDateTime today = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    return new DateTime(
        today.getYear(),
        today.getMonthValue(),
        today.getDayOfMonth(),
        5,
        0,
        0)
    .toDate();
  }
```

I want to use the result of that function as a SQL parameter. The SQL is along the lines of

```
select zip
  from delivery_status
  where delivery_date = :deliverydate
```

And setting the parameter goes a little something like this:

```
public SqlParameterSourceFactory sourceFactory() {

    ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory sourceFactory =
    new ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

    params.put("deliverydate", "#T(com.acme.util.DateTimeUtils).currentDeliveryDate()");

    sourceFactory.setParameterExpressions(params);

    return sourceFactory;
}
```

I've tried variations with/without T, pound sign, parenthesis, and fully qualified name, but I keep getting

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'deliverydate': No value registered for key 'deliverydate'
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(NamedParameterUtils.java:355)
```

Can one of you help me with the correct incantation?

Cheers, y'all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must work like this:

```
"T(com.acme.util.DateTimeUtils).currentDeliveryDate()"
```

No pound sign before `T` operator.

Comment: I can't believe how quickly you Pivotal guys post a response!  

Thanks Artem.  Turns out I was confusing setSelectSqlParameterSource and setUpdateSqlParameterSourceFactory on the JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.  Just me being a dumb newbie, looking for results on the wrong function.  Cheers.